# What is a clean way of defining an array of strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Let's say for whatever reason, I am going to define an array variable in a ruby script file that holds all the US states as strings.  What is a clean way of doing this?  And by clean, I'm not really looking for performance, but more readability.

Here are a couple ways I have tried, but don't really like:

A single **LONG** line definition.  I don't care for this because it is very long, or needs to be word wrapped.

```
states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", ...]
```

Another options would be a multiple line definition, pushing strings to the array.  This resolves the long lines (width-wise), but I don't care for the mixed use of assignment and array.push.

```
states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"]
states.push("Arkansas", "California", "Colorado")
states.push("...")
```

Yet another option would be single line pushes.  This seems consistent, but could be quite long to accomplish.

```
states = []
states.push("Alabama")
states.push("Alaska")
states.push("Arizona")
states.push("...")
```

Now, sure, ideally, I would not be hard-coding my array values and should be pulling them from a database or web service, etc.  But, for the purpose of the question, let's assume that the values do not exist anywhere else currently.

Comment: Just for the records, there are gems which provide this data already. One rather complete one is [Carmen](http://jim.github.com/carmen/).

Comment: Good to know.  Actually, I'm not really looking for a list of states.  I just used that as an example.  I'm pretty sure there aren't any gems that provide lists of gases used by dissolved gas analysis units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put them on multiple lines if you like...

```
states = ["Alabama",
          "Alaska",
          "Arizona",
          "Arkansas",
          "California",
          "Colorado",
          ...]
```

The key is to end the lines with commas.  The following won't work:

```
# Does not work!
states = ["Alabama"
          ,"Alaska"
          ,"Arizona"
          ,"Arkansas"
          ,"California"
          ,"Colorado"
          ...]
```

Comment: that's definitely clean looking.

Comment: I am going to mark this one as the accepted answer.  I think this is the cleanest approach assuming the states will be defined in the script itself and not an external file.  External files is probably the way I would go, but the original question is looking to do this "in a ruby script file".

Comment: Holger's version is the cleanest. Period. :D

Answer (score 8):

There's an actual syntax element in ruby for defining such arrays:

```
> states = %w(Alabama Alaska Arizona
>    Arkansas California
>    Colorado)
=> ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado"]
```

Note though, that it will split the elements on whitespace. So an entry like "North Dakota" will end up as two items: "North" and "Dakota".

Comment: You can escape a space with a backslash.

Comment: nice.  Is there a way to do %w(File.read('states.txt'))?  This specific syntax does not do what I would have expected.

Comment: You could do `File.read('states.txt').split`. Note again that it splits on whitespace. The backslash escape doesn't work here anymore as it isn't ruby syntax anymore but a simple string you are reading.

Comment: @Holger.  Yes on the whitespace.  But, if my file was comma delimited, I could do File.read('states.txt').split(',') and all would be good.  When I originally posted the question, I didn't even think about an external file.  So, I couldn't say at origin if file was formatted any special way.

Comment: %w is convenient, but not sure how if it any more clean, especially if having to escape spaces.

Comment: Also, other delimiters than `()` can be used. I prefer using `%w[foo bar]` which I find more array-like

Answer (score 3):

You could build your data via a string:

```
states = %{Alabama
  Alaska
  Arizona
  Arkansas
  California
  Colorado
  Nort Carolina
}.each_line.map{|s| s.strip}

p states
```

Advantage:
You could store your data in a Text file.

```
states = states = File.readlines('countries.txt').map{|s| s.strip}
```

And countries.txt:

```
Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Colorado
Nort Carolina
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this trick, you'll find it to solve the problem rather neatly.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > text =  %w( hello yo wazzap
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002]> hi
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003]> hello)
 => ["hello", "yo", "wazzap", "hi", "hello"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > text
 => ["hello", "yo", "wazzap", "hi", "hello"]
```

I might also suggests the storing of the data on individual lines in a file, which can then be generated as an array with the simple command:

```
array = File.readlines('input.txt')
```

Comment: Works, as long your strings contain no spaces. (example: North Carolina)

Comment: Thanks for the idea of storing in a file.

Comment: @Ryan that really goes to @knut, I just mention it to point out the way you can read the file in as an `Array`.

Comment: But be aware, File.readlines includes the newlines. That's why [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235043/what-is-a-clean-way-of-defining-an-array-of-strings-in-ruby/7235193#7235193) includes a `map{|s| s.strip}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the states (array values) do not NEED to be defined in the script file itself, based on the all other answers provided, I would probably store the states in a separate comma-separated file and do this

```
states = File.read('states.txt').split(',')
```